# Mysql loop return incorrect data

Tags: foreach, while-loop

Good Afternoon All,

I am facing an issue and cant figure out what I am doing wrong in my myslq/php while/foreach loop.

Loop seems to be duplicating results.

```
////////////////////////Check which site have this app///////////////////
$query_t = "SELECT * FROM site WHERE app_id='2'";
$result_t = mysql_query($query_t) or die(mysql_error());

$rows = array();     
while($r_t = mysql_fetch_array($result_t))
    $rows[] = $r_t;
foreach($rows as $r_t){ 

$this_areport_site_id = $r_t['site_id'];

  //////////////Search for user emails that have access to this app ////////
 $query_t4 = "SELECT mail FROM $user_tbl WHERE arep_kitchen='1' AND site_id='$this_areport_site_id' ORDER BY id ASC";
 $result_t4 = mysql_query($query_t4);

 while ($r_t4 = mysql_fetch_array($result_t4)) {
    $areport_kitchen_email .= $r_t4[mail].',';// append comma after each value you append to the string

 }

echo 'Here: '.$this_areport_site_id.' - '.$areport_kitchen_email.'<br />';

     }
```

Now it does return me following:

```
Here: AHROW - person1@email.com,
Here: AHROW - person1@email.com,person2@email.com,
Here: AHALEX - person1@email.com,person2@email.com,person3@email.com,
```

And I was expecting

```
Here: AHROW - person1@email.com,person2@email.com,
Here: AHLANG - No Records here
Here: AHALEX - person3@email.com,
```

I would appreciate suggestion what I am doing wrong there as I am sitting on this whole morning.

Answer (score 0):

You should empty the string `$areport_kitchen_email` before appending emails to it:

```
$areport_kitchen_email = ''; // empty emails container string

while ($r_t4 = mysql_fetch_array($result_t4)) {
   $areport_kitchen_email .= $r_t4[mail].',';// append comma after each value you append to the string
}
```

This will avoid duplicates.

Comment: Hi Bozzy,

First of all thank you for your reply.

I have looked at this before and with the code you have suggested I do still receive: 
`Here: AHROW - person1@email.com,
Here: AHROW - person1@email.com,person2@email.com,
Here: AHALEX - person3@email.com,`

And I am not sure why it those show this first row? with AHROW there are 2 records, with AHALEX there is one record, and in AHLANG app_id does exist but no user emails under this site.

Comment: Strange. So we have AHALEX correct now, but still two instances of AHROW with different combinations of emails... I would try to comment out the email search part and echoing the content of $this_areport_site_id, to see where the problem is. Let me know if you try this.

Comment: So when I do comment out the search email query and echo $this_areport_site_id it does return `AHROW
AHLANG
AHALEX` which is correct as app_id=2 exist for all of those 3 records.

Comment: Hi Buzzy, the issue is with  $areport_kitchen_email .= $r_t4[mail].','; trying to figure out what.

Comment: Would you try to comment out the latest while loop? Keep only the `$areport_kitchen_email = '';` and the `echo` statements and see what's the output. I can't imagine why the content of `$this_areport_site_id` would change by means of code that only reads its content...

Comment: those return nothing but $this_areport_site_id and comma "," from the $areport_kitchen_email

Comment: Wow! The comma shouldn't be in `$areport_kitchen_email` if the while loop is commented out! There's something strange going on there... Anyway, if you found another solution, better so ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by doing two loops one inside the other and resigning from comma separated string which seems to be an issue in first post.

Bozzy, thank you for an effort.

```
$query_t7 = "SELECT * FROM site WHERE app_id='2'";
$result_t7 = mysql_query($query_t7) or die(mysql_error());
while($r_t7 = mysql_fetch_array($result_t7)) {

$this_areport_site_id = $r_t7['site_id'];

$query_t8 = "SELECT * FROM admins WHERE arep_kitchen='1' AND site_id='$this_areport_site_id' ORDER BY id ASC";
$result_t8 = mysql_query($query_t8) or die(mysql_error());
while($r_t8 = mysql_fetch_array($result_t8)) {

$areport_kitchen_email = $r_t8['mail'];

}
}
```

Comment: Maybe you'd add an `echo` after the `$areport_kitchen_email = $r_t8['mail'];` to output your data, right? I think, however, that this isn't a complete solution, at least if you need to output also the sites without emails (AHLANG in your example), which will not be computed in the second while loop since no records meet the query conditions.